# Node Js Not Being able to Create Object

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to create an object with node js, but for some reason it's not accepting/remembering the code I'm using:

```
    users-mbp:~ user$ node
> var author = { firstName: Alex, lastName: Snail, "age: 28", favoritefood: ['lasagna', 'pizza']};
... author
... author.lastName
... c
> author.lastName
ReferenceError: author is not defined
> var author =  { firstName: 'Alex', lastName: 'Snail', age: '28', favoriteFood { 'lasagna', 'pizza'}
... author
... 
> author
ReferenceError: author is not defined
> author.lastName
ReferenceError: author is not defined
```

Comment: You have the wrong object with missing quotes. Right one should looks something like this `var author = { firstName: 'Alex', lastName: 'Snail', age: '28', favoritefood: ['lasagna', 'pizza']}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the wrong object with missing quotes. Right one should looks something like this

```
var author = { firstName: 'Alex', lastName: 'Snail', age: '28', favoritefood: ['lasagna', 'pizza']}
```